# Opening a file though batch

Tags: batch-file

I have several files i need to open at the same time. They all have no extensions but I would like them to open as a .txt file. My .batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

start "" /max "C:\Users\Documents\%mm%%dd%%yy%\apple"

start "" /max "C:\Users\Documents\%mm%%dd%%yy%\orange"

start "" /max "C:\Users\Documents\%mm%%dd%%yy%\mango"
```

The file opens but for ever file I have to choose what to open as. Is there a way to skip that pop up and bypass it and open it as .txt but at the same time not change the extension of the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" /max notepad "C:\Users\Documents\%mm%%dd%%yy%\mango"
```